# Color coding calendars and/or tagging entries

Tags: calendar, categories

We just started using SharePoint in my organization and have faced some limitations that we're looking to overcome. Among the seemingly simpler challenges is the difficulty we're having sorting through the large number of entries on a shared calendar.

The calendar is meant to keep track of advertising, tradeshows, promotions, etc. We'd like to color code the entries so we can identify what's what at a glance. Similarly, we'd like to add tags to identify the entry as one of the above "categories" so we can just show the tradeshows, for example.

Are we missing these seemingly essential functions of SharePoint? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SharePoint! It's a wonderful world wrought with excitement and new discoveries everyday...

What I would do in your situation is to create a view based on each of the tags. Once each view is created, you can switch back and forth as needed to see each individual view. And you can use each view to color code your items.

Using the default view of the calendar list, in the ribbon, click the Calendar tab, then click Calendars Overlay. From here add each view to each color you want.

HTH

Comment: Oh, here's a post explaining how to do this http://davidlozzi.com/2012/01/26/color-code-your-sharepoint-calendar/

Answer (score 2):

I am using SharePoint 2007 and tried the color coding with Content Editor web part.

I have placed the TextToHTML-v2.1.1.txt file in Style Library on SharePoint Site.

It showed following error on viewing calendar for all other accounts trying to access the site:

> Web Part Error: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform
>   this action or access this resource.

I moved the TextToHTML-v2.1.1.txt file to location where every one has access, now its showing the Calendar with Colors.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this workaround:

http://usermanagedsolutions.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Color-Coding-Calendar-List.aspx

If you are on SharePoint 2010, you can use overlays (cf. David's answer), but you'll be limited to 9 choices.